# Calling opencpu custom function returns error

Tags: opencpu

I uploaded a function (`apistatus5`) into an opencpu store (`ropensci_dash`):

https://public.opencpu.org/R/user/SChamberlain/ropensci_dash/apistatus5/ascii

I put the function into a store within opencpu under my username (`SChamberlain`), but I keep getting the error:

STRING_ELT() can only be applied to a 'character vector', not a 'raw'

Is there some kind of bug detection for opencpu?  The code works fine on my own machine within R, so I am not sure where the bug is when trying to run using:

https://public.opencpu.org/R/user/SChamberlain/ropensci_dash/apistatus5/png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, this is interesting. I am getting the same error on my local R:

```
Error in rjson::fromJSON(httr::content(httr::GET("http://api.plos.org/search?q=id:10.1371/journal.pbio.0000012&wt=json"))) : 
STRING_ELT() can only be applied to a 'character vector', not a 'raw'
```

The `httr::content` function by default returns a `raw` vector, which `fromJSON` doesn't like. If you are not getting this error, this is most likely is due to different versions of the R packages (rjson or httr) on the server than on your local machine. I think you need to update `httr` and replace `content` by `text_content`. Also `RJSONIO` package is a bit better than `rjson` I think.

However, I realize this is very hard to debug. I have to think about this a bit how to improve this.

Comment: What version of httr is running on your servers? The most recent on CRAN is 0.1.1. I was using the github version, but just tried with the CRAN 0.1.1 version instead. `text_content` works, but throws errors `text_content() deprecated. Use content(x, as = 'text')`

Comment: It has the current version on CRAN: `httr_0.1.1`

Comment: Here's the new version: https://public.opencpu.org/R/user/SChamberlain/ropensci_dash/apistatus7/ascii   It still throws error `missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`.

Comment: ahk, it was `httr`. now it works with RCurl instead  https://public.opencpu.org/R/user/SChamberlain/ropensci_dash/apistatus8/png

Comment: There is another issue with `httr` causing weird side effects when being attached. I'm looking into this...

Comment: Thanks for looking into the httr problem. I would like to transition to `httr` instead of `RCurl` as it it easier to use.